# Select Element from Different Lists using Multiple Criteria

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have the following basic question. I have created the following lists of number

```
list1= {0.17280394634580676`, 0.16592518527179198`,  0.16565012961313136`, 0.16913887913796202`, 0.17532555997800134`, 0.1709799900459552`, 0.1727886004102705`, 0.17309929761671264`,  0.16684725512423282`, 0.19030846458674544`}
list2 = {0.17386342603139585`, 0.19088582236184554`, 0.23203374070590962`, 0.2369946021621591`, 0.1952022726800119`, 0.23686981987007244`, 0.1980693337605245`, 0.23829147261528855`,   0.14379878667926133`, 0.18123073864910402`}
```

and i want to select only these elements that have simultaneously a larger value from 0.17 in list1 and a value that is lower than 0.19 in list2 and append them in a new list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
criteria = {criterion1, criterion2} = {GreaterThan[.17], LessThan[.19]};

Join @@ MapThread[Select[#]@#2 &, {criteria, {list1, list2}}]
```

> ```
> {0.172804, 0.175326, 0.17098, 0.172789, 0.173099, 0.190308, 
>  0.173863,0.143799, 0.181231}
> ```

> ***"how can I also find the positions in lists1 and 2 of each element that is appented in the joint list?"***

```
KeySelect[criterion1] @ PositionIndex[list1]
```

> ```
> <|0.172804 -> {1}, 0.175326 -> {5}, 0.17098 -> {6}, 0.172789 -> {7},
> ```

```
 0.173099 -> {8}, 0.190308 -> {10}|>

KeySelect[criterion2] @ PositionIndex[list2]
```

> ```
> <|0.173863 -> {1}, 0.143799 -> {9}, 0.181231 -> {10}|>
> ```

Comment: Dear kglr thank you for your quick response. This is a really nice solution! Do you have any idea, how can I also find the positions in lists1 and 2 of each element that is appented in the joint list?

Comment: @Smaug, please see the update.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. This is exactly what I was looking for! :D